# compress wave file on server and decompress in flash / client side

Tags: flash, actionscript, wave

im using an open source program called Festival that generates text to speech, and in ubuntu i call its method text2wave that converts text into a wave file. I am looking into converting short paragraphs to wave files, but the problem is that each wave file ends up being approximately 1.2MB in size. The wave file is recorded at 16khz, and while recording at 8khz halves the size of the wave file (sacrificing sound quality), the wave file is just simply too large. These paragraphs have to be served many times to the clients and our server can not support that much bandwidth.

Does anyone have any idea how to bypass this problem? Is it possible to compress the file on the server, and decompress it in my flash script (on the client side) and play the wave? How much size would i be saving? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash supports the mp3 format. You can encode your wave file on the server side with [LAME](http://lame.sourceforge.net/), and let Flash do the decoding on the client side. I'm assuming you can use arbitrary CGIs on your server. How much size you'll save this way depends on your encoding settings. you should experiment.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but the file size dropped from roughly over 1.2MB to 1.1MB, not a significant improvement :(

Comment: Are you sure you tried different options? You can compress down to 8 kbits/sec wich should be a huge improvement. Try `lame -b 8 infile.wav outfile.mp3` and change the `-b 8` option to taste. Higher will be higher quality but bigger file size.

Comment: you sir are a genius. got the file down to 40kb. sounds a little rough, but this is perfect, i will continue to fiddle with the settings. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to hear! But the real geniuses are those who actually wrote LAME :)